# How to export my current installed Antergos system to an .iso?

Tags: export, installation, archlinux, iso

I want help creating an .iso file from my current installed Antergos system with all the customizations .I want the created image to have preinstalled all the packages and programs I have . But folders like downlods , documents and others not to be included.

I am a new user and dont know how to search for something like that .All my search end up on information about how to install antergos from usb :smile: .

Comment: I think it's kind of impossible cause you're gonna create so many other errors that you gonna lost your time to debug them all but I answered you question.

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated but I don't reject the idea that it's possible...

If you want to make a *"rescue"* CD then you can use [Archiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso) which is probably what you were thinking about.

You can also "Remaster the install ISO" as explained in the [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO).

Comment: After hours of searching , I decided that this is over my league , so I am going to learn more about archlinux before considering creating my custom ISO .